# ngResource doesn't work when parse HTML from JSON file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngresource

I am trying to get blog posts from json file and parse 'description' in HTML format. I use ngResource, but I don't get anything

This is sample data from json

```
  jsonFeed({
    "title": "My Blog",
    "description": "",
    "modified": "2016-05-10T21:21:46Z",
    "items": [
     {
        "title": "Title1",
        "description": "<p><a href=\"#">Paul<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <img src=\"https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7365/26872407641_cfbb210ee7_m.jpg\"/>"
   },
   {
        "title": "Title2",
        "description": " <p><a href=\"#">Beth<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p><img src=\"https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7287/26333398074_cfbce73532_m.jpg\" />"
   }
  ]
  })
```

app.js

```
 var app = angular.module('blogApp',['ngResource']);
 app.filter("sanitize", ['$sce', function($sce) {
   return function(htmlCode){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
  }
 }]);
 app.controller('BlogController', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope){
var blog = this;
blog.posts = {};
  $http.jsonp('url').success(function(data){ 
});
jsonFeed = function(data){
$scope.posts = data.items;
}
```

index.html

```
  <body ng-app="blogApp">
    <div ng-controller="BlogController as blog">
        <div class="post" ng-repeat="post in posts">
            <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
            <div ng-bind-html="'{{post.description}}' | sanitize"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

In the result I just get this

```
   {{post.description}}
```

Also tried to inspect element in console

```
  <div ng-bind-html="'<p><a href="#">Paul<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <img src=\"https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7365/26872407641_cfbb210ee7_m.jpg\"/>' | sanitize" class="ng-binding">{{post.description}}</div>
```

Why can't I parse and see html of description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do use controller alias `blog`, when you are referring posts to looping over it.

```
<div class="post" ng-repeat="post in blog.posts">
```

And then

```
<div ng-bind-html="post.description | sanitize"></div>
```

**Note**: I can't see any ngResource related code there in your question. Do you missed anything to add in question?

Comment: changing to <div ng-bind-html="post.description | sanitize"></div> fixed problem. Thanks!

Comment: @user6145338 do accept my answer, so that will give direction to other who is looking for same issue. Thanks :-)

Comment: @user6145338 no problem, Thanks :-)